# Disambiguate the [sphinx] tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

The [sphinx](/questions/tagged/sphinx) tag (no tag wiki) is mainly used for questions about two unrelated tools: the [Sphinx documentation generator](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) and the [Sphinx search engine](http://sphinxsearch.com/). There are also a few [sphinx](/questions/tagged/sphinx)-tagged questions about a speech recognition toolkit called [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/).

I would like to suggest some retagging to distinguish these tools. Perhaps the tag could be split into [sphinx-docgen](/questions/tagged/sphinx-docgen), [sphinx-search](/questions/tagged/sphinx-search), [sphinx-speech](/questions/tagged/sphinx-speech), or something similar?

**Update**: Now there is a tag wiki for [sphinx](/questions/tagged/sphinx), but it only mentions the search engine.

**Update 2** (2011-07-18): Retagging work is ongoing. Questions about the documentation tool should be tagged [python-sphinx](/questions/tagged/python-sphinx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: disambiguation of [sphinx](/questions/tagged/sphinx), [python-sphinx](/questions/tagged/python-sphinx) and [cmusphinx](/questions/tagged/cmusphinx) is now done!